# ASP.NET Core MVC MD5 Hasing is not equal with online MD5 generator

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, hash, md5

I trying to do MD5 hash. Im compare my result with 3 MD5 online generator. But the result is different.
What am I doing wrong?

```
private static string GenerateHash(string value)
    {
        var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
            data = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create().ComputeHash(data);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    }
```

Calling the function:

```
ViewBag.Secret = GenerateHash("asd");
```

The result is: eBVpbsvxyW5olLd5RW0zDg==

But on the online generator the result is:7815696ecbf1c96e6894b779456d330e

(im not using salt)

Comment: Why are you using MD5 in the first place? It's woefully insecure and shouldn't be used for anything.

Comment: The first result is Base64, the second result is Base16. Both results are 16-byte buffers with almost identical contents, but the Base64 one has a different final byte... weird. I suspect you copied-and-pasted into the online generator incorrectly?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out, I changed the ToBase64String to Hex BitConverter.ToString and the result will be the same as the online generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, reproduced in my local and it's getting the same value with the online `Hash Generator`.

```
        public static string GetMd5HashNewMethod(string inputNew)
        {
            using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
            {
                // inputNew = "Palnati"
                byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputNew);
                byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

                return Convert.ToHexString(hashBytes); // .NET 5 +
             // return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
                
            }
        }
```

***Output from Code & Online:***

```
7b1ea3d03dafd1626817916e13a207e1

7b1ea3d03dafd1626817916e13a207e1
```

`@kajahun123` - Yes, you are right we have to use `.ToHexString()` from .NET 5+